Creatures entering modified and Tribute to the World Tree
If I have a Maja, Bretagard Protector, Trostani Discordant, and a Tribute to the World Tree on the battlefield, when I create a 1/1 token the Tribute to the World Tree would see that the token entering is a 1/1 before the buff effects modify the token so I wouldn't get the draw off of Tribute to the World Tree, correct?
Also, in a similar set up if I have a Sigil Captain on the battlefield and Tribute to the World Tree and a 1/1 token enters I can pick the order of which triggered ability goes first so I can put the two +1/+1 counters on the token and then draw off World Tree because the token is a 3/3 now right?

Your expectations here don't seem to be consistent. You think you wouldn't get the draw in the first case because the token wouldn't enter with the buff, but that you could get the draw in the second case by buffing the token after it enters.

I think the simplest case to explain is having 2 Tribute to the World Tree. The first trigger resolves, sees a 1/1 and makes it a 3/3. The second trigger resolves, sees a 3/3 and draws a card.

If a creatures enters the battlefield as a 3/3 because of continuous effects, you will draw a card from Tribute. If you would buff that creature to 3/3 with a triggered ability, you get to choose whether you want to draw a card or get the counters from the Tribute.
The buff from Maja and Trostani are static abilities. They are active all the time and creatures affected by them enter with the buffs already in effect.

604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.

A 1/1 token would enter as a 3/3, and Tribute to the World Tree would make you draw a card.
The buff from Sigil Captain is a triggered ability just like Tribute, and triggers off the same event (a creature enters the battlefield). Since you control both Tribute and the Captain, you get to choose their order of resolution.
What I believe you misunderstood is that Tribute checks the creature's power only once, when it resolves.

If Sigil Captain's ability resolves first, it puts 2 +1/+1 counters on it, then Tribute will see a 3/3 and you draw a card.
If Tribute resolves first, it puts 2 +1/+1 counters on it, then Sigil Captain sees a 3/3 and, since Sigil Captain only affects 1/1 creatures, nothing else happens.


You shouldn't be able get a 5/5 creature with Sigil Captain. As mentioned in the rulings, Sigil Captain's ability has an "intervening 'if' clause" so we check again if the creature is 1/1 when the ability resolves, and if it isn't then the ability does nothing.

@ZoeH Correct, thanks
